# Expanding variables in file contents

Tags: powershell, variables

I have a file `template.txt` which contains the following:

```
Hello ${something}
```

I would like to create a PowerShell script that reads the file and expands the variables in the template, i.e.

```
$something = "World"
$template = Get-Content template.txt
# replace $something in template file with current value
# of variable in script -> get Hello World
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Great question! I just needed to figure out how to do the same thing.

Comment: Just to reiterate a comment on an answer below, I do not know of a way to do this (variable expansion) that does not allow arbitrary expressions to be executed. I gave up on powershell variables and used environment variables with `[System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables()` instead. Any **safe** solution using powershell variables would be very interesting!

Comment: I have a tool that uses ExpandString on a templpate.  But before invoking ExpandString,  it defines powershell variables using actual values pulled from a csv file.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Another option is to use ExpandString() e.g.:

```
$expanded = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($template)
```

Invoke-Expression will also work.  However be careful.  Both of these options are capable of executing arbitrary code e.g.:

```
# Contents of file template.txt
"EvilString";$(remove-item -whatif c:\ -r -force -confirm:$false -ea 0)

$template = gc template.txt
iex $template # could result in a bad day
```

If you want to have a "safe" string eval without the potential to accidentally run code then you can combine PowerShell jobs and restricted runspaces to do just that e.g.:

```
PS> $InitSB = {$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Applications.Clear(); $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Scripts.Clear(); Get-Command | %{$_.Visibility = 'Private'}}
PS> $SafeStringEvalSB = {param($str) $str}
PS> $job = Start-Job -Init $InitSB -ScriptBlock $SafeStringEvalSB -ArgumentList '$foo (Notepad.exe) bar'
PS> Wait-Job $job > $null
PS> Receive-Job $job
$foo (Notepad.exe) bar
```

Now if you attempt to use an expression in the string that uses a cmdlet, this will not execute the command:

```
PS> $job = Start-Job -Init $InitSB -ScriptBlock $SafeStringEvalSB -ArgumentList '$foo $(Start-Process Notepad.exe) bar'
PS> Wait-Job $job > $null
PS> Receive-Job $job
$foo $(Start-Process Notepad.exe) bar
```

If you would like to see a failure if a command is attempted, then use $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString to expand the $str parameter.

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding something, but as far as I can tell `ExpandString()` is not safer at all... It still does expression expansion, which means in your example, specifically, everything in C:\ still gets deleted! Did you mean to indicate that even with `ExpandString()` arbitrary code **will also** be executed?

Comment: (in the example above, `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($template)` results in an equally bad day!)

Comment: @Tao, yep you're write on the lack of safety with ExpandString. See the updated answer for a better approach.

Comment: cool, I have to play with this, looks great! Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 7):

I've found this solution:

```
$something = "World"
$template = Get-Content template.txt
$expanded = Invoke-Expression "`"$template`""
$expanded
```

Answer (score 3):

Since I really don't like the idea of One More Thing To Remember - in this case, remembering that PS will evaluate variables and run any commands included in the template - I found another way to do this.

Instead of variables in template file, make up your own tokens - if you're not processing HTML, you can use e.g. `<variable>`, like so:

```
Hello <something>
```

Basically use any token that will be unique.

Then in your PS script, use:

```
$something = "World"
$template = Get-Content template.txt -Raw
# replace <something> in template file with current value
# of variable in script -> get Hello World    
$template=$template.Replace("<something>",$something)
```

It's more cumbersome than straight-up InvokeCommand, but it's clearer than setting up limited execution environment just to avoid a security risk when processing simple template. YMMV depending on requirements :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is my take on the task. It makes use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.4), like @PaoloTedesco's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1667774/213871), but uses string interpolation in [multi-line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28291800/213871) strings and also don't trim newlines in the output. The script assumes `Version.cs.in` is the template file, that should be expanded to `Version.cs`:

```
$VERSION="1.0.0"
$versioncs = Get-Content -Path "Version.cs.in"
$versioncs = $versioncs | %{ Invoke-Expression "`@`"`n$_`n`"`@" }
Set-Content -Path "Version.cs" -value $versioncs
```

I fed it with the following template:

```
using System.Reflection;
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("$($VERSION)")]
```

And I correctly get:

```
using System.Reflection;
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0")]
```