# string variable not substituted in multi-line string

Tags: string, powershell, concatenation, multiline, substitution

Here is the code/output all in one:

```
PS C:\code\misc> cat .\test.ps1; echo ----; .\test.ps1
$user="arun"
$password="1234*"
$jsonStr = @"
{
        "proxy": "http://$user:$password@org.proxy.com:80",
        "https-proxy": "http://$user:$password@org.proxy.com:80"
}
"@
del out.txt
echo $jsonStr >> out.txt
cat out.txt
----
{
        "proxy": "http://1234*@org.proxy.com:80",
        "https-proxy": "http://1234*@org.proxy.com:80"
}
```

Content of string variable `$user` is not substituted in `$jsonStr`.

What is the correct way to substitute it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The colon is the [scope](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) character: `$scope:$variable`. PowerShell thinks you are invoking the variable `$password` from the scope `$user`. You might be able to get away with a subexpression.

```
$user="arun"
$password="1234*"
@"
{
        "proxy": "http://$($user):$($password)@org.proxy.com:80",
        "https-proxy": "http://$($user):$($password)@org.proxy.com:80"
}
"@
```

Or you could use the format operator

```
$user="arun"
$password="1234*"
@"
{{
        "proxy": "http://{0}:{1}@org.proxy.com:80",
        "https-proxy": "http://{0}:{1}@org.proxy.com:80"
}}
"@ -f $user, $password
```

Just make sure you escape curly braces when using the format operator.

You could also escape the colon with a backtick

```
$jsonStr = @"
{
        "proxy": "http://$user`:$password@org.proxy.com:80",
        "https-proxy": "http://$user`:$password@org.proxy.com:80"
}
"@
```